# React: Nested Array shows as undefined when trying to map

Tags: arrays, reactjs

My nested array passed from props cannot be mapped. Trying to map tasks. Array.isArray() returns true in child component, so not sure why can't map.

**Updated per suggestions, but still giving same error**

Array:

```
  export const PeopleArray = [
        {name: 'Parent',
         tasks: [ 
             {category: 'Category1',
             },
             {category: 'Category2',
             },
             {category: 'Category3',
             },
             {category: 'Category4',
             },
             {category: 'Category5',
             },
             {category: 'Category6',
             },
             {category: 'Category7',
             },
             {category: 'Category8',
             },
             {category: 'Category9'
             },
         ]
        },
```

Parent:

```
                    PeopleArray.map( (person,i) => {
                        return (
                            <PeopleCard
                              key={i} 
                              name={person.name} 
                              tasks={person.tasks}
                            />
                        )
                    })
```

Child

```
<ul className='taskList'>
    {    
         this.props.tasks.map( (task,i) => {
              return(
                 <li key={i}>{task.category}</li>
               )
         })
    }
```

Comment: Have you  called super(props) in the child constructor?

Comment: Hello, yes.constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cardStyle: 'peopleCardBody hideCardBody',
            arrowStyle: 'arrowDefault'
        };
    }

Comment: I see that you are not returning anything from your second map function. Either change the brackets { } to be parentheses for automatic one line returns or add a return statement to see if that fixes it

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose **task** in `{ }` . Please update child component as:

```
<div className={this.state.cardStyle} >
        <ul>
              {    
                this.props.tasks.map( (task,i) => {
                     <li key={i}>{task.category}</li>
                })
               }
                     
       </ul>
 </div>
```

Also, task is an object with key category. Please update it.

Comment: Hi, I completed this, but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to return value from mapping in addition to drilling to category via curlies

```
<div className={this.state.cardStyle} >
        <ul>
              {    
                this.props.tasks.map( (task,i) => {
                     return <li>{task.category}</li>
                })
               }
                     
       </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I called the child component a second time, but forgot to pass props. That is why it was returning as undefined; the props array didn't exist.